# How does Chalmers' "hard problem" differ from the "mind-body problem"?

Tags: consciousness, mind-body

They both seem be be asking how neurological processes can give rise to consciousness. Is there a real difference between the two questions, or is one just a reformulation of the other?

Comment: As far as I understand, the hard problem simply identifies those aspects of consciousness, namely qualia, for which Chalmers claims we can never observe any sort of neural correlate.  If this is correct, then the hard problem is simply Chalmers way of focusing the mind-body problem on those problems he believes to be insurmountable.

Comment: It's a variation, but I'd call it re-formulation of the old metaphysical problem. Some philosophers have hoped to rebrand it as a scientific problem but it remains stubbornly metaphysical. Category-errors breed like rabbits in this area of research.  .